# Matplotlib Scatterplot legend for points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am programmatically creating a scatterplot like this:

```
(Ipython sample code)
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg="1.0")
d1 = [range(1,11)]
d2 = [range(1,11)]
dcolor = ['red','red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue', 'blue']
colordict{'red': 'monkey', 'green':'whale', 'blue':'cat'}
ax.scatter(d1,d2,alpha=0.8, c=dcolor,edgecolors='none',s=30)
```

I would like to add a legend for each different point, so that the legend contains a point in the given color and the name from colordict. Is that possible without splitting the creation of the scatterplot into multiple calls to scatter? Since this happens in a automated library, I would rather avoid to have different calls to scatter().

Comment: `Since this happens in a automated library, I would rather avoid to have different calls to scatter().` I didn't get that. Why is this a problem?

Comment: A) it looks ugly as hell. B) it introduces code which differs between the one  "only x,y" and the "x,y,color" case and C) it's code which needs to be verified to work in a lot of circumstances

Comment: I didn't get B and C. But feel free to criticise my suggested code.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably do the following.

```
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg="1.0")

g1 = ([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
g2 = ([4,5,6], [4,5,6])
g3 = ([7,8,9,10], [7,8,9,10])
data = (g1, g2, g3)
colors = ("red", "green", "blue")
groups = ("monkey", "whale", "cat") 

for data, color, group in zip(data, colors, groups):
    x, y = data
    ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=group)
plt.legend(loc=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like keeping the data and its symbols (color, label) even tighter than cel does. I find the code more readable and more *checkable*, and often I'm getting them together out of some datasource anyway:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg="1.0")
zoo=[]
zoo.append(([4,5,6], [4,5,6], "blue","ape"))
zoo.append(([1,2,3], [1,2,3], "red","monkey"))
for x,y,c,l in zoo: 
    plt.scatter(x,y,c=c,label=l)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have used the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg="1.0")
d1 = [range(1,11)]
d2 = [range(1,11)]
dcolor = ['red','red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue', 'blue']
ax.scatter(d1,d2,alpha=0.8, c=dcolor,edgecolors='none',s=30)

import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='a')
patch2 = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='a')

fig.legend( [patch, patch2],['abc', 'xyz'], loc = 'lower center', ncol=5, labelspacing=0. )
```

Here it is not yet in a loop, but that is easily doable.